# How to add form fields dynamically using webform

Tags: 7, webforms

Using webform 3 module, is there a way to dynamically add more fields or do these fields have to be created in the database first?
Currently that's what I am doing and with javascript toggling the css display attribute to show or hide fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question and the accepted answer over at Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592932/drupal-6-x-add-more-module-no-end-to-adding-more

Basically, the answer is no. This issue ([354381](https://www.drupal.org/node/354381)) addresses the problem. From the module's author:

> [...] there is no progress on this subject. The ability to support multiple values requires a tremendous amount of re-architecting, including changes to the way CSVs are generated, analysis, the database structure, and the UI (both for administrators and users). I wouldn't expect this feature to be added any time soon.

A possible workaround is provided at the StackOverflow question linked above. In summary, you could create a content type (or, for Drupal 7, a block type using [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) might be slightly more appropriate). And then give anon users permission to create that entity - simulating a webform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Webform Add More](https://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore) module to dynamically add more fields in webform.
The project page says:

> Webform Add More enables selected fieldsets to be initially hidden and
>   progressively shown with an Add more button, mimicking CCK multiple
>   fields. This module adds a checkbox
>   setting to webform fieldset components to select which should have Add
>   more functionality, as well as an advanced setting to override the
>   button label per Webform

Comment: The Add more module is very poor. It doesn't dynamically add fields in the database but shows/hides instead. Also it fails to load when I style my form or use Arrange fields.